# Advice on general-purpose autocompletion (REST)

Tags: php, mysql, rest, autocomplete

I need some advice on the topic of autocompletion for a general purpose search box.
When a user types into the search box, I would like the back end to return results for:

- People (other users);
- Coming up event (activity) names;
- Keywords;

I have three routes in my back end (REST), but the plan is to make 1 route `v1/search`to manage the queries for autocompletion.
What I am uncertain about is if a union query on the (expected every-growing) tables won't result in a very slow execution of the autocomplete?
Is this strategy good, or would you advise on a better one?

Even with caching in place, for many queries (eg. search event by name / search person by name), the queries still need to be executed.

Comment: You may want to cache the results of those queries to memory using a caching technology like [Memcached](http://memcached.org/), it sounds like something that won't be written to much in comparison to the amount of reads.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm going to do this. But for the structure of the queries themselves, I'm not convinced that my solution is viable.